# get disqus_identifier of a blogger thread

Tags: blogger, disqus

My blogger page is http://avi-win-tips.blogspot.com/p/clipjump.html

I want to get the `disqus_identifier` for that page so that I can sync the comments of that page with a newer page. I use the [API Console](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472121-testing-the-api-using-the-console-) to get details about the desired page but see no details about the `disqus_identifier`.

[Here is](http://pastebin.com/kRxqUDPQ) what I got from console. What can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Blogger is a somewhat special case - no identifier is set, but we use a strong URL reference (as in it doesn't change depending on what's in the window).

Instead you'll want to look for `disqus_blogger_current_url` on your page, and match that up to a `disqus_url` on the synced page, assuming you're using the universal code and not the regular Blogger integration.

Comment: how to get `disqus_blogger_current_url` ? Not obtained from console.